# adding custom css file priority in magento2

Tags: magento2, css, custom-theme

I have added custom CSS file in custom theme with below code in

> [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout /
>   default_head_blocks.xml

```
 <head>
   <css src="css/custom.css" />      
 </head>
```

I want the **custom.css** file to load fist before the **style-m.css**

I tried with **order="100"** but that doesn't load the CSS file first.

How to make the CSS file to load first? Can anyone help me, Thank in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no `order` attribute, by doing this, you'll have an exception.

To place your `custom.css` **before** `style-m.css`, you'll need to declare it before `style-m.css` in your layout `default_head_blocks.xml`.

To place it **after**, you'll just need to add `media="all"` in xml declaration like this :

```
<css src="Magento_Theme:css/custom.css" media="all" />
```

Comment: what should style-m.css contains?, I am not declared the style-m.css anywhere, it is coming from parent luma theme

Comment: I have declared only custom.css, style-m.css load from luma, so how to declare it before?